# Documentation from XML Doc in VS

Tags: visual-studio, documentation-generation

Tell me, please, is it possible to generate from standard XML Doc in Visual Studio a proper documentation? With exports from xml into user-friendly look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx) for one.

There are several different projects that deal directly with this:

- [GhostDoc](http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/archive/2007/05/01/2473036.aspx)
- [Sand Castle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)
- [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Ghost Doc + Sand Castle is that what i need.

Comment: See http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/b772e00e-1705-4062-adb6-774826ce6700.htm

Answer (score 1):

No, I think you need something like NDoc for that.

http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a brief look on it.

Answer (score 1):

We use ghostdoc
http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx 
http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/archive/2007/05/01/2473036.aspx
for producing the docs

And to generate the docs SandCastle that you find on Codeplex
http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/

Getting started 
http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/b772e00e-1705-4062-adb6-774826ce6700.htm